# pandas function with isin

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as like this:

```
aa        bb  cc
[a, x, y] a   1
[b, d, z] b   2
[c, e, f] s   3
np.nan    d   4
```

I'm trying to create a new column like this:

```
aa        bb  cc dd
[a, x, y] a   1  True
[b, d, z] b   2  True
[c, e, f] s   3  False
np.nan    d   4  False
```

My current solution is:

```
def some_function(row):
    if row['bb].isin(row['aa'])==True:
        return True
    return False
df['dd'] = df.apply(lambda row: some_function(row), axis=1)
```

But this throws out an error `("'str' object has no attribute 'isin'", 'occurred at index 0')`

I suspect, because I'm missing something when it comes to checking the `isin`.

Essentially, I need to check if the str value of `bb` is in column `aa` which has a list in each cell.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need parameter `in` for check membership in list:

```
df['dd'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.bb in x.aa, axis=1)
print (df)
          aa bb  cc     dd
0  [a, x, y]  a   1   True
1  [b, d, z]  b   2   True
2  [c, e, f]  s   3  False
```

EDIT:

```
df['dd'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x.bb in x.aa) and (x.cc == 1), axis=1) 
print (df)
          aa bb  cc     dd
0  [a, x, y]  a   1   True
1  [b, d, z]  b   2  False
2  [c, e, f]  s   3  False
```

Or:

```
df['dd'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.bb in x.aa, axis=1) & (df['cc'] == 1)
print (df)
          aa bb  cc     dd
0  [a, x, y]  a   1   True
1  [b, d, z]  b   2  False
2  [c, e, f]  s   3  False
```

EDIT:

```
df['dd'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.bb in x.aa if type(x.aa) == list else False, axis=1) 
print (df)
          aa bb  cc     dd
0  [a, x, y]  a   1   True
1  [b, d, z]  b   2   True
2  [c, e, f]  s   3  False
4        NaN  d   4  False
```

Comment: Oh thanks @jezrael How about if it's a conditional logic. i.e only if df['cc']==1?

Comment: Ah thanks! Just one last question. How would you deal with missing values? Often there are blank values in df['aa']. I've updated the question with the example.