# Pandas function isin error - 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, data-analysis

Here's what I'm trying to do

variable = ['Apple','Blueberry','Chocolate']

So basically, what I'm trying to do is to add a new column and if Col A is present in the variable defined above, this new column should have values from Col B. If it doesn't, it should get the value from Col C

Expected output

[image]

It looks pretty straightforward and I'm clear on what I'm trying to do but for some reason, I'm getting an error with the lambda function that I'm trying to use

Here's my code -

```
final['Final'] = final.apply(lambda x:x['Col B'] if x['Col A'].isin(variable) else x['Col C'],axis=1)
```

If I run this, I'm getting an error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'

what am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

Edit : isin or in both returns an error

Comment: You can use `final['Col A'].isin(variable)` with `np.where` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806827/pandas-function-with-isin

----------
This post is similar to what I'm trying to achieve, only difference is that my variable is not present in the table already. It HAS to exist as a user defined variable as part of the code

Comment: It doesn't matter, change `isin` to `in`.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh can't. it throws me syntax error

Comment: What error it gives you?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh 
Syntax error. 

Here's what I did
final['Final'] = final.apply(lambda x:x['Col B'] if x['Col A'].in(variable) else x['Col C'],axis=1)

Comment: Check the duplicate post to see the syntax of `in`

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh You're right. Thank you. "in" worked.